# using multiple streams to multiple files gives System.ObjectDisposedException "Cannot access a closed file."

Tags: c#, stream

I want to have multiple loggers writing to different files.  The writing part works but when I close the Logger object I get System.ObjectDisposedException "Cannot access a closed file."

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Logger logger1 = new Logger("file1.txt");
        Logger logger2 = new Logger("file2.txt");
        logger1.WriteLog("abcd");
        logger2.WriteLog("abcd");
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
}

class Logger
{
    private StreamWriter writer;

    public Logger(string filePath)
    {
        writer = File.AppendText(filePath);
    }

    ~Logger()
    {
        try
        {
            writer.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }

    internal void WriteLog(string p)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel, why not use something like nlog with common.logging?

Comment: Remove the disposable method and use the Using keyword for each Logger instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to what's stated in the question you are not closing any logger. I assume that this exception happens on the finalizer thread when `Logger` is being finalized. This is because finalization order is not guaranteed. The `StreamWriter` probably died first.

Delete the finalizer. It serves no purpose since the `StreamWriter` closes itself on finalization (or the stream that it writes to; not sure). And you can't deterministically flush all data out anyway (see the comment below). This strategy is doomed. You need to throw this away.

Implement the disposable pattern and switch to deterministic cleanup.

Comment: But that almost guarantees that some part of the log won't be written to the file. Without a call to `Close`, the buffer won't be flushed. Whereas it's true that `Dispose` calls `Close`, that only happens if the internal `Dispose` is called with the `disposing` flag set to true. And that won't happen in the finalizer. You can test this easily enough by writing a program that opens a `StreamWriter`, writes a short string to it, and then exits without calling `Close` or `Dispose`. The file will be empty.

Comment: That's why I'm saying: Implement the dispose pattern and close all objects deterministically.

Comment: Wow. I need to step away from SO. This is the third time today I've overlooked crucial information in a question or answer. I flat did not see your suggestion to implement the `Dispose` pattern. My apologies.

Comment: Don't delete your comment. It is valuable.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is open a file, write a short message and close it, in a small app like the one you've posted, you could consider using [`File.AppendAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
File.AppendAllText("file1.txt", "abcd");
```

You could even keep your "Main" code as-is, and write a short helper function to use. This eliminates the need to dispose anything, since `File.AppendAllText` takes care of it for you.

```
class Logger
{
    private readonly string logFileName;

    public Logger(string logFileName)
    {
        this.logFileName = logFileName;
    }

    internal void WriteLog(string message)
    {
        File.AppendAllText(logFileName, message);
    }
}
```

Granted, an advantage of `StreamWriter` is that you don't hit the disk every time you write a message, unless you've set `AutoFlush` to `true`. YMMV.